# Users with <5K rep should not see the suggested-edit queue enabled, on per-site metas

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

Apparently, the only possible thing to review in the suggested-edit queue from per-site metas are suggestions on tag excerpts and tag wikis.

I don't have the necessary reputation yet to review such type of suggestions, but I'm still able to see that queue enabled. Is this by design? If yes, why?

[image]

Likewise, the meta review queue on the main site should only be enabled when users reach **3k rep** (and get access to Close Votes and Reopen Votes queues, in the per-site meta).

[image]

Comment: [Partly requested on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276226/review-link-in-navigation-bar-shouldnt-appear-on-meta-at-500-rep) (by me :)

Comment: The same thing happens on Area 51, which is annoying.